# Matching two separate nth-of-type in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to match two different div classes by their corresponding index number. However, I am unsure how to go about achieving this. The goal is to fadeIn each `.info` by clicking on the respective `.press`, but the way I have gone about this seems inefficient.

My JSFiddle is below.

https://jsfiddle.net/e0o2nauL/

```
$(document).on("click", ".press:nth-of-type(1)", function(){
$(".info:nth-of-type(1)").fadeIn();});
$(document).on("click", ".press:nth-of-type(2)", function(){
$(".info:nth-of-type(2)").fadeIn();});
$(document).on("click", ".press:nth-of-type(3)", function(){
$(".info:nth-of-type(3)").fadeIn();});
```

The HTML

```
<p class="info">Information 1</p>
<p class="info">Information 2</p>
<p class="info">Information 3</p>
<div class="press"></div>
<div class="press"></div>
<div class="press"></div>
```

Each `.info` corresponds with `.press`, as shown in the jQuery's `nth-of-type`. However, I am not certain how to tie indexes to each `nth-of-type().`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it simply by using the `index()` function,

```
var info = $(".info").hide();
$(document).on("click", ".press", function(){
  info.eq($(this).index("div.press")).fadeIn();
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kms7zetr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can work with `index` and `eq` here, but in general I would recommend, that you improve your markup instead. I'm aware, that this solution might not be applicable, but often it helps, taking a step back and rethinking your current approach and often you come up with a solution that's more elegant.

E.g., you could create markup like the following, even making use of semantic tags:

```
<details>
    <summary></summary>
    <p>Information 1</p>
</details>
```

This way you wouldn't even need to use classes. Now writing a jquery selector for this would be much easier, wouldn't it?

If this approach does not work for you, I would go with an explicit coupling which does not make you dependent on an explicit order in your markup.

```
<p data-info="1">Information 1</p>
<p data-info="2">Information 2</p>
<p data-info="3">Information 3</p>
<div data-press="1"></div>
<div data-press="2"></div>
<div data-press="3"></div>


$(document).on("click", "div", function(){
    $("p[data-info="+$(this).data("press")+"]").fadeToggle();
});
```